# Where to find the csharp loader for Googles Code Prettify

Tags: c#, google-code-prettify

Im trying to setup a code highlighter for my up coming blog, however...
it seems like code prettify has dropped the support for csharp(C#) or they have hidden the loader somewhere else.. any ideas?

I just checked out their github repo and cant find the loader there..

Br,
Inx

Answer (score 1):

It's already included, proof from their [GitHub](https://github.com/google/code-prettify#for-which-languages-does-it-work):

```
<pre class="prettyprint lang-html">
      The lang-* class specifies the language file extensions.
      File extensions supported by default include
        "bsh", "c", "cc", "cpp", "cs", "csh", "cyc", "cv", "htm", "html",
        "java", "js", "m", "mxml", "perl", "pl", "pm", "py", "rb", "sh",
        "xhtml", "xml", "xsl".
</pre>
```

Comment: In OP's case, use lang-cs.